# Application not finding EditText

Tags: java, android, view

EditText is being a end of year nightmare, and I when finding view by ID, seem to be returned with null when getting text from it.

Settings Activity:

```
public class Settings extends ActionBarActivity {

    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        createPreferences();
    }

    public void createPreferences(){
         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("emailAddress", 0);
         getData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void getData(){
        email = getEmail();
    }



    public String getEmail(){

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        EditText usernameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_address);
        String Username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();

        if (Username.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return Username;
        }

        System.out.println(email + "    8888888888888888888");
        if(Username !=null){
            email = Username;
        }

        if (email==null){
            SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("emailAddress", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
            //check preferences.
            String emailNew = setting.getString("emailAddress", "n").toString();

            if(emailNew != null){
                email = emailNew;
            }


            if(email==null){
            //shit  

            }

        }
        if(email!= null){

        }
        return email;
    }
}
```

Settings XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.keepsafe.Settings" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email_address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enteremail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_enter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email_address"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email_address"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_address"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email_address_toSendto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enteremail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password_enter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_enter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SettingsSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password_enter"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password_enter"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="dataSubmit"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea, and I have been battling this with google for a few hours.

Any help is appreciated, I'm new to this.

Comment: remove that second `setContentView` inside `getEmail`

Comment: Try @android:id/email_adress

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below @BobbleHead

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the step as mentioned below :**

Don't use the `setContentView()` method inside your `getEmail()` method.

**So the code after the above edits would look as below :**

```
   public class Settings extends ActionBarActivity { 

    String email;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        createPreferences(); 
    } 

    public void createPreferences(){ 
         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("emailAddress", 0);
         getData(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true; 
    } 

    public void getData(){ 
        email = getEmail();
    } 



    public String getEmail(){
        //Removed setContentView() from this method
        EditText usernameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_address);
        String Username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();

        if (Username.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return Username;
        } 

        System.out.println(email + "    8888888888888888888");
        if(Username !=null){
            email = Username;
        } 

        if (email==null){
            SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("emailAddress", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
            //check preferences. 
            String emailNew = setting.getString("emailAddress", "n").toString();

            if(emailNew != null){
                email = emailNew;
            } 


            if(email==null){
            //shit   

            } 

        } 
        if(email!= null){

        } 
        return email;
    } 
}
```

**Just a Suggestion :** Reference your `Views` in `JAVA` after `setContentView` in your `onCreate()` method  and declare them globally in case you want to access them in many functions.
Hope this Helps!

Comment: This didn't fix it, sadly. Now trying with the views in onCreate

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Nope, even in onCreate the EditText is still not found.

Did get this error in logcat...

12-31 19:00:25.370: E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper(833): Failed to get contextual suggestions.
12-31 19:00:25.370: E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper(833): package name: com.example.testApp
12-31 19:00:25.370: E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper(833): Error message: Disabled

Comment: Could you please post the modified code? , so that I can help you.

Comment: I changed onCreate to include

`usernameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_address);
String Username = usernameET.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(this, Username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: No, My code won't include Username in onCreate, please check again

Comment: I believe so; it seems for some reason that the email address inputs overlapped one another in the app. This meant i was inputting text into a different field. Bum.

Comment: Ok let me know for any other help